# ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'mysql'

Tags: mysql

I'm doing some activities in the database. I dropped a database and then recreated it. All seemed well, but when I tried to create a user to access it, I received this error:

> ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist

So, I tried to access to the database "mysql" but I recieved this error:

> ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'mysql'

Indeed the database `mysql` is now missing, but everything else works. I have other databases in this instance and they work.

How can I recover the missing `mysql` database without losing data of other databases?

Comment: What activities? What database did you drop and recreate? How? Show some context for what led up to this.

Comment: Looks like you dropped one too many databases. That one should not be removed or this will happen. If you've nuked out the `mysql` database you've made quite a mess of things and recovery isn't always easy.